# Where can I go skydiving in South Korea?

Tags: south-korea, parachutes-skydiving

I am heading to Korea in near future for quite a long trip. 
As, I am very enthusiastic about skydiving, I was wondering how easy (or hard) to get a tandem jump (aka assisted jump).

After Google, I found something on [skydivingschool.co.kr](http://skydivingschool.co.kr) which is completely in Korean language. Some discussion around it describes that instructions are in Korean only.

Is there any other foreigner-friendly diving agency (or school) out there ?

Comment: so you're looking for one in English, in particular?

Comment: since North Korea just declared war on 31 March 2013, you might want to pending your holiday to Korea.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with Rudy. North Korea has technically been at war with South Korea for over 50 years now. (A peace deal was never signed) The rhetoric has certainly increased recently, however there is no concern to visit South Korea today.

Comment: @MarkMayo yeah, "english" is the fact

Comment: @Rudy How do you know that he isn't trying to drop into North Korea through the DMZ? :)  There is actually a famous saying by someone "Война войной а обед по расписанию".  You can translate it to get at the meaning. :)

Comment: @Karlson ha ha ... :D

Comment: @karlson : "war is war, lunch is scheduled." Not sure what does it mean... Just saying that kmonsoor might want to see how the situation goes before going. Note that even General Motors has already consider to move the production to somewhere else if the situation goes worse... If there no particular event for the following weeks - please go and have fun! :)

Comment: @Rudy *war is war, lunch is scheduled." Not sure what does it mean* - All it means that war is war but my scheduled fun is taking place no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any schools aside from the one you have listed.  Generally speaking I would always start from the sports associations like [Korean Parachute Association](http://www.kpa.or.kr) but their site is all in Korean and rather poorly done too.

There is also a Sky Divers' forum called [Drop Zone](http://www.dropzone.com/dropzone/Asia/South_Korea/) which has a section dedicated to South Korea.  It might provide some information but I didn't feel like registering to get at the content (sorry).

There also is a list of [Dropzones](http://www.jumpticketprices.com/dropzones.asp) across the world and prices to access them as well as clubs servicing them but nothing in South Korea.